# Apr_sockaddr_info_get() Failed

Tags: apache2

Today while trying to start apache server I received an error:

```
Apr_sockaddr_info_get() Failed
```

I would like to get opinions / answers to resolve this issue.

I would like to know what exactly is wrong with my current setup and what are correct steps I need to take to resolve it.

Just to start apache server I referred to http://www.webune.com/forums/apr-sockaddr-info-get-failed.html and server started without error but I don't see website coming online yet.

I'm not exactly sure what all information is required to resolve it, you guys can ask me and I'll reply with required information

Comment: is your ServerName defined in your httpd.conf?

Answer (score 8):

Fix your hosts file at `/etc/hosts`.

1) From command line type `hostname` to get your hostname. Example output might be `example.com`

2) Edit `/etc/hosts` and change the lines to match your hostname. Example:

```
    ::1 localhost.example.com localhost
    127.0.0.1 localhost.example.com localhost
    192.168.1.104 example.com example
    192.168.1.104 example.com.
```

3) Open your httpd.conf file and make sure ServerName is defined. If it is not add `ServerName example.com`

4) Restart apache via command line `apachectl -k graceful` OR `apachectl -k restart`

Comment: For multiple domains, would you simply add in the other sites to the hosts file?

Comment: @Mat-visual yes, as many as you like.

Answer (score 3):

just try the following steps:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

***Most probably the file will be empty.***

Just add the following line, and you are done!

```
ServerName localhost
```

*[ localhost will be the servername. ]*

Then you can restart service by typing the code below:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```